# Not able to fetch updated content from div contenteditable on keyup event

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, salesforce-lightning

I am implementing this using `lightning-web-components`.

I am using `<div contenteditable>` to apply different styling to multiple lines.

Here, `assetSerialNumber` and `assetLocation` gets populated in `connectedcallback()` method in js.
I am using `divTextarea` in class to make `div` look like `textarea` which is working fine.

`.html file`

```
<div id="divcontenteditable" class="divTextarea slds-textarea" contenteditable onkeyup={handleChange}> 
   <p>Device request:  {assetSerialNumber}</p>
   <p>Device location {assetLocation}</p>
</div>
```

`.js file`

```
handleChange(event) {
        var input = this.template.querySelector(".divTextarea");
        console.log(input.innerText);
        console.log(input.textContent);
    }
```

**Scenario 1:** If I am adding any text to either of `<p>` tags under `<div contenteditable>`, `handleChange` method is able to retrieve updated text values.

**Scenario 2:** If I press `ENTER` and starts typing, **I am not able to get updated text**. Everytime `ENTER`is pressed, a new `<p>` is added under `<div contenteditable>` like below and `handleChange` method still returns the original text`

```
<div id="divcontenteditable" class="divTextarea slds-textarea" contenteditable onkeyup={handleChange}> 
       <p>Device request:  {assetSerialNumber}</p>
       <p>Device location {assetLocation}</p>
       <p>New text</p>
 </div>
```

How can I achieve scenario 2 i.e. to fetch updated content when text is added in a new line.

Comment: Hi, what is your question? What are you trying to achieve? You can edit your question.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to solve issue in scenario 2 . I have updated question to reflect this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get updated content from div with below approach. I removed default text from html file and added those in innerHTML in js file. Then I was able to get updated content from input.textContent.

`html file`

```
<div id="divcontenteditable" class="divTextarea slds-textarea" contenteditable 
onkeyup={handleChange} lwc:dom="manual"></div>
```

`js file:`

```
let divTextarea = this.template.querySelector('.divTextarea');
divTextarea.innerHTML = '<p>'+Device request:+' '+this.assetSerialNumber+'</p>'+'<p>'+Device location+' '+this.assetLocation+'</p>';
```

and then onkeyup event will handled like below:

```
handleChange(event) {
   var input = this.template.querySelector(".divTextarea");
   console.log(input.textContent);
}
```